# Showing that $\int^{\infty}_{\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} ~ dx$ has a improper Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Observe that,
$$\int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}~ dx  = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\int^{(k+1)\pi}_{k\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx.$$

Let, $\alpha_k = \int^{(k+1)\pi}_{k\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Observe that, $\{|\alpha_k|\}_{k \ge 1}$ is monotonically decreasing, and
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} |\alpha_k| \le \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int^{(k+1)\pi}_{k\pi}\frac{1}{x} ~ dx  = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \ln(\frac{\pi k + \pi}{\pi k} ) = 0.$$
By the alternating series test we can conclude that,
$$\int^{\infty}_{\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Any mistakes in this proof? Thanks!

Comment: There is a detail missing because if you integrate $\frac{\sin x}{x} + \cos x$ for example, you have the same $\alpha_k$.

Comment: @Gribouillis, I don't understand why that is a problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Johndoe it's a problem because the integral in the comment does not converge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the OP it is rigorously shown that the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{n\pi}\frac{\sin x\,dx}{x}
$$
exists in $\mathbb R$. What is necessary to prove thought is that
the limit
$$
\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_0^{M}\frac{\sin x\,dx}{x}
$$
exists in $\mathbb R$.

To complete the proof, say
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{n\pi}\frac{\sin x\,dx}{x}=\ell$ and
let $\varepsilon>0$. Then it is already established that there exists an $n_0\in\mathbb N$, such that
$$
n\ge n_0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \left|\int_0^{n\pi}\frac{\sin x\,dx}{x}-\ell\,\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
$$
If now $M>n_0\pi$, then, for $n_M=[M/\pi]\ge n_0$, we have
$$
\left|\int_0^{M}\frac{\sin x\,dx}{x}-\ell\,\right|\le
\left|\int_{n_M\pi}^{M}\frac{\sin x\,dx}{x}\right|+\left|\int_0^{n_M\pi}\frac{\sin x\,dx}{x}-\ell\,\right| \\
\le \frac{M-n_M\pi}{n_M\pi}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\le
\frac{\pi}{n_M\pi}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \le
\frac{1}{n_0}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon,
$$
provided that $n_0>2/\varepsilon$.

Comment: Every time I see someone using both a limit as a natural variable goes to infinity and a limit as a real number goes to infinity, I become a little sad that the notation is ambiguous. Especially in this case, where the entire point is that one is proven to exist and the other isn't (yet), and you really can't see which is which and have to resort to context and assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I did not realize there was a difference but the difference makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 4):

An elementary approach: integrate by parts, so that

$\displaystyle \int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=-\frac{1}{\pi}-\int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^2}dx$

and observe that the second integral in this expression converges absolutely.